# Delete record by time in InfluxDB-CXX

Tags: c++, influxdb

Reference: https://github.com/offa/influxdb-cxx

It is easy to delete record by time using CLI interface,

```bash
delete from imagetable where time='2022-11-16T19:42:41.945508272Z'
```

but I am not able to figure out how to do the same with influxdb-cxx. i.e. not able to access the time through C++ interface.

e.g. Tags can be accessed with function `points[0].getTags()` but how to access the time ?

Have already tried to access it with `points[0].getTimestamp()` but not able to print it in this format in C++ `2022-11-17T03:37:25.934547412Z`

can anyone please help ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What's the code you have? Can you make a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) out of it?

Answer (score 0):

In influxdb-cxx you can use `InfluxDB::execute` [method](https://github.com/offa/influxdb-cxx/blob/1a3c4ceaf355b67e330b18db2664fb195142e410/include/InfluxDB.h#L96) to execute InfluxQL statements like from your example for CLI interface. Regarding timestamps, they are saved as `std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::system_clock>` ([source](https://github.com/offa/influxdb-cxx/blob/1a3c4ceaf355b67e330b18db2664fb195142e410/include/Point.h#L87)) in the library's `Point` class, which denotes Unix (epoch) time excluding leap seconds (which is what timestamps in InfluxDB represent). Your example uses RFC3339 notation to provide timestamp, but InfluxQL also directly understands "nanosecond count since epoch" notation for it ([example](https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v1.7/query_language/data_exploration/#specify-a-time-range-with-epoch-timestamps)). So, it isn't necessary to represent `Point`'s timepoint in RFC3339 notation to use it in `execute` command (which is possible, but harder and reduntant), you can just use standard C++ chrono library functions to get nanoseconds since epoch for given timepoint. Example:

```
using namespace std::chrono;
auto nsEpoch = duration_cast<nanoseconds>(points[0].getTimestamp().time_since_epoch()).count();
idb->execute("delete from imagetable where time=" + std::to_string(nsEpoch));
```